# Meshlab selecting alternate texture

Tags: textures, meshlab

We have an situation where we'd like to be able to let the user change the mesh "skin" but retain the same geometry, using OBJ files in meshlab.  For example, putting different color codings (slope, surface roughness, shadow enhancement) on the same mesh that is derived from stereo analysis.

There is a Filters/Texture/Set Texture option, but it does not work at *all*, at least not on the mac (fresh build I just downloaded).  It insists on looking in /Applications for the texture and gives me an error saying pathnames are not allowed if I try to do give it a full pathname (??!!).  I mean, it should at least look in the same directory you loaded the mesh from.  I even tried "open" from a Terminal window where I was cd'd to the proper directory, and it instead looked in / .

But even if it worked, that's a really clunky interface.

What I'd really like to be able to do is to define two (or more) textures in the .mtl file... two separate "newmtl" entries.  That much is possible.  But the textures must be referred to in a "usemtl" statement in the .obj file.  And therein lies the problem... I do not want to duplicate my hundreds-of-MB mesh files just to change one line to use a different texture.  Nor do I want to edit the .mtl file to change the tag name - these are supposed to be read-only files for the users.

Is there any way to tell meshlab "substitute texture B for texture A"?  This seems like an easy thing to do - and rudimentary compared to all the other capabilities of meshlab.

If not - and it appears there isn't - can we request that such a feature be added?